# "I wish I got..." versus "I wish I had got..."

Tags: difference, perfect-constructions

Are these sentences grammatically correct and do both possess almost the same meaning?

> I wish I got good marks.
>
> I wish I had got good marks.

Comment: Your second sentence is incorrect. You should use *I wish I had gotten good marks.* And no, they are not the same. The first is of simple past tense and the second of past perfect (not progressive).

Comment: @Abbasi Not in British, Australian, Irish, New Zealand or South African English. That's only true of US English. In UK English the past participle of *get* is *got*, not *gotten*.

Comment: DO NOT CLOSE THIS PERFECTLY GOOD AND USEFUL QUESTION!!!!

Comment: @Araucaria It is hard to see how this question differs much from any other "is this grammatically correct?" question. Nevertheless, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @Mick Well, potentially the meaning is different between the two sentences because of the modally remote tense usage that's mandatory for complements of the verb *wish*. So it's generally useful for learners :) imo ...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are correct.

No, the meanings differ:

- ***I wish I got good marks*** — a wish about the present, it means something like *“I sometimes receive bad marks, I think about receiving good ones”*;
- ***I wish I had got good marks*** — a wish about the past, means something like *“I received bad marks in the past, now I regret that they weren't good”*.

There's also a third option:

- ***I wish I would get good marks*** — a wish about the future, means something like *“I will soon receive some marks, I want them to be good ones”*.

Comment: "I wish I would get good marks" sounds odd to me.

Comment: Okay, But can you please explain the meaning of first one to me more clearly?

Comment: It's the most general one of the three. It refers to a present state, so if you are a student and you wish your current marks were better, you use this one.

Answer (score 0):

**I wish I would get good marks** is not possible. The subjects must be different when we use "would" after wish to refer to a future change that is unlikely to happen.

Which sentence is correct:
a."I haven't got a car but I wish I had."
b. "I haven't got a car but I wish I did."
c. "I don't have a car but I wish I had."
d. "I don't have a car but I wish I did."?
Thank you!

Comment: "I wish I would get good marks" is perfectly correct.  Your second paragraph is a separate question and should be asked as such.